# How to Disable PasswordBox Hover,Focused,Mouse effects

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, styles, passwordbox

I am trying to disable hover and mouse over effects of password box. Because i am setting passwordbox Style property to my custom property and they are overlapping. How can i disable passwordbox's default effects?

Here is the xaml of the passwordBox and its style

```
<PasswordBox x:Name="PassBox" MaxLength="40" PasswordChar="*" MinWidth="250" Style="{StaticResource PasswordBoxWithValidation}" Margin="10" />
```

Here is the style of the passwordbox

```
<Style x:Key="PasswordBoxWithValidation" TargetType="PasswordBox">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red" />
            <Setter Property="ToolTipService.ShowDuration" Value="20000" />
            <Setter Property="ToolTip">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ToolTip DataContext="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
                        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=(Validation.Errors)}" DisplayMemberPath="ErrorContent" />
                    </ToolTip>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your style you could try setting:

```
<Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
```

Or explicitly specify the setter properties to disable the effects that you do not want (although I don't actually know what these are).

Answer (score 0):

Every control has its own style and behavior, so you have to override default style using.

```
<Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
```

When you override default style, you have to implement template of control(PasswordBox).

```
<Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
              <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type PasswordBox}">
                     <!--- Implement your logic here -->
              </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```